# How to pass a parameter to mysqlsh shell command?

Tags: mysqljs, mysql-shell

```
mysqlsh --host=127.0.0.1 --port=3306 --user=root --password=rootpw 
         --file my.js $tableName
```

How can I pass the `$tableName` parameter dnymically ot the `my.js` file?

I tried first reading the argument in the js file, but that already fails:

```
print("Table name:", argument[0]);
```

How can arguments be accessed?

Comment: If you using node to execute your js script (like: `node my.js tableName`), you should use `process.argv[2]` as first argument for script.

Comment: But I'm using `mysqlsh` in bash shell, as written above

Comment: So it is `$1`. Use following:   
`mysqlsh --host=127.0.0.1 --port=3306 --user=root --password=rootpw 
         --file my.js $1`

Comment: Well but the problem is not setting the parameter in the calling `mysqlsh` script, but *reading* it in the *.js script! Because `argument[0]` seems not to exists.